# How to make a search query for a JSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

G'day,

So i've got this code to display a JSON file in a table and it works. What I want to know is how can I add a search bar for the table (I want to search by postcode)

```
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {
    var Data = [
    {
     "Service name": "3Bridges Community Incorporated",
     "Physical Address Line 1": "1/72 Carwar Avenue",
     "Physical Address Suburb": "CARSS PARK",
     "Physical Address State": "NSW",
     "Physical Address Post Code": 2221,
     "Care Type": "Home Care Places",
     "Residential Places": null,
     "Home Care Low Places": 35,
     "Home Care High Places": 10,
     "Transition Care Places": null
 }
 ]
    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in Data[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.className += "alt";

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = Data[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div id="showData"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say do a onchange event to a text input, and every time user defocus the text box, it will call your createTable function with a zip in parameter.

```html
function search(zip)
{
  CreateTableFromJSON(zip);
}
function CreateTableFromJSON(zip) {
    var Data = [
    {
     "Service name": "3Bridges Community Incorporated",
     "Physical Address Line 1": "1/72 Carwar Avenue",
     "Physical Address Suburb": "CARSS PARK",
     "Physical Address State": "NSW",
     "Physical Address Post Code": 2221,
     "Care Type": "Home Care Places",
     "Residential Places": null,
     "Home Care Low Places": 35,
     "Home Care High Places": 10,
     "Transition Care Places": null
 }
 ]
    //apply filter
    Data=Data.filter(d=>d["Physical Address Post Code"]==zip || !zip)
    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in Data[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.className += "alt";

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = Data[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

HTML .

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
     <input type="text" name="searchText" value="" onchange="search(this.value)">
    <div id="showData"></div>
</div>
```